# Where does the output of dd() and dump() get written when developing Laravel in VS Code?

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a Laravel 8.x app in the current version of VS Code. I have a dump() statement in a Controller that I've written so that I can determine precisely what's in the $request that is being handled because I suspect that my date isn't exactly what I think it is. I've added this to the store() method: `$request->dump()` and I'm pretty sure it has executed but I can't find the output from the dump() function anywhere. I've got Debugbar installed and it does not show the dump() output. Ditto for any window of the browser like the console, inspector, etc. I've looked in the laravel.log but it's not there either. I've checked each of my terminal windows - the ones dedicated to php artisan serve and npm run watch and the one I use for all other commands but I can't find anything there. I'm out of ideas on where to look.

If the Laravel docs tell you where to find the output, I missed it; they describe what dump() and dd() do but I can't find where they describe where the output is written.

I'm pretty new to Laravel and I'm working alone so I have no work colleagues to ask. Could someone kindly tell me where to find the output of dump() so that I can debug this program?

Comment: `dump()` and `dd()` usually output to the browser

Comment: Where did you place `$request->dump()` statement? view or controller?

Comment: the response would have been returned to your browser

Comment: @brombeer - Where in the browser can I find the output?

Comment: @Saeid Asadi - As I said in the question, $request->dump() is in the store() method of my controller.

Comment: @lagbox - Can you be more specific about where I will find the dump() output in the browser? I looked in each of the tabs, console, inspector, etc. and didn't see it but maybe I have to drill down within one of the tabs.

Comment: it would be displayed on the page (like every other page would be) ... in the source code would be a bunch of html for this as that is what `dump` does it creates a pretty html output

Comment: use `$request->dd()` instead and  see if you can get the results in the browser. using `dump` makes the application continues. So the `dump` method results might be mixed up with other view contents and gets hidden sometimes.

Comment: Right in the browser on the page that you are calling. Yep, use `dd()` to stop execution of the script, might be you are redirected to a different page. Or, use beyondcode's Laravel Dump Server

Answer (score 0):

None of the comments pointed me to precisely where I eventually found the dd() output so I'm posting it here for the sake of any future person who has the same issue. I finally found it in the browser, in the console tab (I'm using Firefox) and within the Response to the Axios statement that tried to write the new record to the database. Here's a picture:

[image: location of dd() output from Laravel controller]

I had assumed that the information wouldn't require me to drill down as far as I did; I thought it would be as visible as normal console.log() output.

I'm very grateful to those who replied to my question; you finally got me looking in the exact right place. I've never used dd() or dump() before, even in vanilla PHP, so I really had no idea where the output got written.